# Copying Features from One ArcMap window to another, without losing Related Tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relationship-class, personal-geodatabase, relates

In our current workflow we are working in a Personal Geodatabase with few features and related tables , many persons will be working in different schemes.

When we need to merge these schemes\Pgdb to a single output , we are copying feature class to feature class . Obviously this changes the Object ID in the resulting output Geodatabase and we lose the related table Information.

Is there any way to copy feature classes from different inputs Pgdbs and still preserve the related table ?

Comment: Can you rebuild your relates with ID fields that are not ObjectID fields?

Comment: I am not sure, but the situation is like , a feature class is made of different subtypes and this Origin feature class subtype deals with the related table by means of Object ID.. Primary key is Object Id and there is a foriegn key.. Thanks for giving a viewpoint for me to give a try..

Comment: You have relationship-class as a tag but do not mention using one.  Are you?  Also, why Personal rather than File Geodatabases?

Comment: Hi, we are using PGDB, as the final deliverable to client is a Pgdb. This seems a necessary step as of now. Regarding the Relationship class, yes we use that. Like each electrical service point has a relationship class with customer address. I am able to copy the feature + related table and classes to another new Geodatabase, but to merge 2 or 3 such Pgdb's to a single with the relationship class intact , its difficult I think